# ReferenceField and Wtforms

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-wtforms, flask-mongoengine

I have a connexion problem with *mongoengine* and *wtforms*.

I tried to attribute permission to `User class` with `Role class` but I can't attribute `Role class` foreign key to `User class`

This is my code :

```
# On class File
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, ReferenceField

class User(Document):
    username = StringField(unique=True)
    password = StringField()
    role = RefrenceField(Role, default=Role.objects.get(num=3))

class Role(Document):
    num = IntField()
    name = StringField()

# On form File 
from wtforms import Form, StringField, SelectField

class UserEditForm(Form):
    username = StringField(u'Username', [validators.required()]
    role = SelectField(u'Role', [validators.required()], choices=[(r.id, r.name) for r in Role.objects])
```

When saving, i've this error message :

```
ValidationError: ValidationError (User:53a14fb0cdc4674abf452f2d) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['role'])
```

I tried to remplace `r.id` by `r` and `r._object_key()` but no result

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer : `SelectField` doesn't return good type element for `ReferenceField`.

So this is my new code :

```
# form File
class UserEditForm(Form):
  username = StringField(u'Username', [validators.required()])
  role = SelectField(u'Role', [validators.required()], choices=[(r.num, r.name) for r in Role.objects], coerce=int)

# Controller class
class EditUser(MethodView):
  def get_context(self, id):
    usr = User.objects.get(id=id)
    form = UserEditForm(request.form, usr)
    return {"usr": usr, "form": form}
  def post(self, id):
   context = self.get_context(id)
   form = context.get("form")
   if form.validate():
     usr = context.get("usr")
     form.populate_obj(usr)
     usr.role = Role.objects.get(num=form.role.data)
     usr.save()
     return redirect("/user_edit/" + id)
   return response("form error validation")
```

Have a nice day